# Unable to align Text in the toolbar with the overflow menu

Tags: android, xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/blue_grey_900"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:elevation="5dp"/>
```

Note, that I've used `"?attr/actionBarSize"`, and not `android:"?attr/actionBarSize"` as many other answers have mentioned. I still can't resolve the issue.

Here's how it looks.

[image]

Comment: could you post a picture to describe the result you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Comment: This is from official blog, see [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).